# Run Rscript for multiple samples (files)

Tags: r

I have used the following script for calculating the median for one file (gene). However, I have 20,000 files for which I want to run this R script and get 200 separate output files

```
 #!/usr/bin/R
 setwd("/location folder")

 d <- read.table("tgf.txt", header=FALSE)

 x <- aggregate(d[, 2], list(d$V3), median)

 write.table(x, "tgf.output.txt", quote=FALSE, row.names=TRUE)

 q()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use `list.files` and `grep` to select only the `.txt` in your directory. A `for` loop can read-aggregate and save the files one at the time.

```
all.files <- list.files("/location folder")
txt.files <- grep(".txt",all.files,value=T)

for(i in txt.files){
  d <- read.table(paste("/location folder",i,sep=""),header=F)
  x <- aggregate(d[, 2], list(d$V3), median)
  write.table(x, paste0(i,".output.txt"), quote=FALSE, row.names=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Why not just `list.files(pattern = "*.txt")`? The `grep` is not required.

Comment: And looping when vectorized operations are available is de-optimization.

Comment: And there's some inconsistent usage: `paste(..., sep="")` on line 5 and `paste0()` on line 7.

Comment: considering the nature of the question I thought that it was more important to show possibilities rather than one single point of view. `paste` and `paste0` achieve the same but in different ways (e.g. `sep=""`).  I tend to split commands involving `list.files` and `grep` as it makes easier to read and to reuse. The content of `all.files` is hard to miss. Finally the usage of the `apply`family is not easy to grasp for new user, while loops are much intuitive. Furthermore, `apply` is not always better than a nice `for`, especially in an example like this.

Comment: Showing possibilities is great! However, I don't think a loop would perform as well as or better than vectorized operations. While a loop is easier for people that know basic programming, the `apply` family solves a lot of problems, especially when there is a learning opportunity such as this one, where the task is well defined and how apply works can be easily understood.

Comment: Just encountered this particular gotcha, so we might have to be careful about using `T`/`F` instead of `TRUE`/`FALSE` as well: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/r_language_for_programmers/#assignment

Answer (score 3):

Please do not use `setwd` in a script, it changes working folder without explicit specifications from the user, so the results could be unpredictable for people that are not familiar with the content of the script.

Create a tab-separated file with input filename and output filename, or at least a file with all input files, unless you can pick them using a `list.files(pattern = "<pattern_here>")`. Read this file as a `data.frame` and use it with an `apply`, so a function processes the df row-by-row. Let's say the file (named `metadata.txt`) is:

```
in_file out_file
tgf.txt tgf.output.txt
abc.txt abc.filtered.txt
xyz.txt xyz.randomname.txt
```

Define a function called `process_row()` in the Rscript:

```
process_row <- function(r) {
    d <- read.table(r[[1]], header = FALSE);
    x <- aggregate(d[, 2], list(d$V3), median);
    write.table(x, r[[2]], quote=FALSE, row.names=TRUE);
}
```

And do the actual work:

```
meta_data <- read.table('./metadata.txt', sep = ' ', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
apply(meta_data, 1, process_row(r))
# You don't need a q() in an Rscript because it exits after the last line of code anyway.
```

Comment: I tried the above script but it is giving me following error

Error in read.table(r[[1]], header = FALSE) : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection
Called from: read.table(r[[1]], header = FALSE)

Comment: What is the content of `./metadata.txt`, which is in the working directory where you're running R?

Comment: It worked. Thank you

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked. Thank you